# How can I get variable name from params string[] args in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this method

```
public static string GetName(HttpContext context,  params string[] args)
{
    var key = arg+"="+args.ToString();
}
```

Inside this method I wanna create a a variable key to append all the parameters being passed in the `params[]`.

so for example If I have three variables

```
var A = 1;
var B = 2;
var C = 3;
```

Then I call this method `GetName(context, A.ToString());`

Key should be: `A=a`

but If I call it with `GetName(context, A.ToString(),B.String());`

Key should be: `A=a; B=2`

How can I get A and B names.

`args.ToString()` will get me the value.

Any Suggestions.

Comment: name of variable isn't passed only value is passed. so you can't find out the name of variable passed as an argument to a method.

Comment: If `var A = 1;` then why you would get `A=a` as a result?

Answer (score 6):

You aren't going to get the variable names in this manner, only the values.

Do you need to pass a params array? Perhaps a `Dictionary<String, String>` would be a more realistic data structure for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks I will try this solution.