# Is it possible to easily get variable names in a method as well as their values

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following my [Is it possible to have a Function that takes any number of variables of any type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461003/is-it-possible-to-have-a-function-that-takes-any-number-of-variables-of-any-type)

I have the function that gets any number of any type of variables and it works perfectly

```
 public string funcVars(params object[] paths)
    {
        string strVars = String.Join(", ", paths.Select(x => x.ToString()));

        return strVars;
    }
```

To call it I'd simply need to

```
string someString ="asd"; int someInt = 123; bool someBool=false;
funcVars(someString,someInt,someBool);
```

And the output would be

```
asd,123,false
```

is there any simple way I can also get the variable names as well as their values, so the output would be

```
asd,123,false,someString,someInt,someBool //(or any other similar form)
```

Or do I need to hardcode the names every time I call my method ?

```
funcVars("someString","someInt","someBool",someString,someInt,someBool);
```

Comment: Summary of the duplciate: if you really need this you will need to pass in a `Dictionary<string,object>` to hold the variable names instead of using `params object[]`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I don't think this is a dupe.  The names of the variables are not needed; the OP just needs to be able to identify which is which inside the `funcVars` method.  Using a dictionary of objects here is less-than desirable and not in keeping with the spirit of OO.  The values are not strongly typed and will be boxed.  I suggest creating a class instead.

Comment: I am kinda on the fence, on it. It really does seam like a duplicate to me, but I will re-open it because I honestly don't like the power having a gold C# badge gives me to close with a single vote. Link to the original question I marked as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478187/how-can-i-get-variable-name-from-params-string-args-in-c

Comment: You can use the StackTrace and StackFrame classes in the System.Diagnostics namespace to determine the names of method parameters. Frame 0 is the currently executing method.

Comment: Deleted my answer, it wouldn't have worked in this particular case. All it would have produced was the name of the paths parameter.

Answer (score 2):

What you really should be doing is creating a class to hold your variables:

```
internal class MyValues
{
    internal string SomeString { get; set; }
    internal int SomeInt { get; set; }
    internal bool SomeBool { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can pass an instance of your class:

```
var mv = new MyValues() { SomeString = "asd", SomeInt = 123, SomeBool = false };
funcVars(mv);
```

Here is `funcVars`:

```
public string funcVars(MyValues values)
{
    string strVars = 
        String.Join(", ", new[] { values.SomeString, 
        values.SomeInt.ToString(), values.SomeBool.ToString() });

    return strVars;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight up stealing roy.ap's code and adding the "nameof()" method since getting the name of the property seemed to be apart of the question.

```
class Program
{
    internal class MyValues
    {
        internal string SomeString { get; set; }
        internal int SomeInt { get; set; }
        internal bool SomeBool { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mv = new MyValues() { SomeString = "asd", SomeInt = 123, SomeBool = false };
        Console.WriteLine(funcVars(mv));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string funcVars(MyValues values)
    {
        string strVars =
            String.Join(", ", new[]
            {
                nameof(values.SomeString), values.SomeString,
                nameof(values.SomeInt), values.SomeInt.ToString(),
                nameof(values.SomeBool), values.SomeBool.ToString()
            });

        return strVars;
    }
}
```

There really isn't a way to get the variable names via the the function itself because the scope changes once you're in the method.  That is even if you pass an array of objects, if you perform a foreach to go through each object you will give the individual objects a new scope specific name.

Answer (score 1):

### No, because the variables are not actually passed

No it is not possible, because the variables themselves are not actually passed.  Their *values* are passed.

Consider this code:

```
string someString ="asd"; int someInt = 123; bool someBool=false;
funcVars(someString,someInt,someBool);
```

In your call to `funcVars`, all the parameters are [passed by value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t0za5es.aspx).  All three variables are copied, and copy of them is put on the stack.  These stack variables are identified by completely different symbols-- (e.g. `paths[0]`,`paths[1]`, etc.)

After all, what would happen if you called it like this?

```
funcVars("Hello",245+25,test != null);
```

Obviously those values do not have variable names.  There is no way your function can possibly retrieve what doesn't exist.

### Use ExpandoObject instead

The [System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) seems like a really good fit for this problem.

```
var args = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
args.SomeString = "hello";
args.SomeInt = 32;
args.SomeBool = false;
funcVars(args);

public static string funcVars(ExpandoObject inputs)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in inputs)      
    {
        sb.Append(String.Format("{0} = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```